# Loading locale at runtime is not updating same time

Tags: android

I created one activity which haves one TextView and Spineer. Spineer is used to select locale and on selection I want TextView text should be picked from selected locale and I want it to be changed instantly when spineer goes off.
On onItemSelected method I have written below code:

```
selectedLocale=(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

        if(selectedLocale.equals("Arabic")){
            locale2= new Locale("AF");
        }
        else
        {
            locale2= new Locale("EN");
        }



        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale2;
        Log.v("This file @onItem selected", "calling updatinon" + selectedLocale); 

        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

My issue is that I'm not able to fetch text for selected locale. Can any one update me if I am missing some thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am written wrong flow of code in onItemSelected which was called every time after setting updated locale which was resetting the locale to old locale.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lower case` of language code,for example:

```
new Locale("ar");
```

`ar` leads to `Arabic` local.

Comment: Its not working if i make changes locale name in lower case.My question is to notify system that configuration changes has been done and revert that changes on Activity now.